# SQL returns no result in Java, although it always returns a result in Postgres

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

When I run this query in Postgres Database:

```
select iid from original where accid=1000 and msg_number=1669;
```

it always returns a result in Postgres DB, but when I run it in Java, it returns no result.

This is `original` table:

```
iid: int4
accid: int4
msg_number: int4
```

This is my Java code:

```
public String getIID(String msgNr) {
    String accid=null;
    try {
        Statement accidStmt = conn.createStatement();
        String accidQuery = "select accid from accounts where name='" + clientname + "'";
        ResultSet accidResult = accidStmt.executeQuery(accidQuery);
        while (accidResult.next())
            accid = accidResult.getString("accid");
        accidResult.close();
        accidStmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    String iid = null;
    try {
        String iidQuery = "select iid from original where accid=" + accid + " and msg_number=" + msgNr;
        // String iidQuery = "select iid from original where accid=" + Integer.parseInt(accid) + " and msg_number=" + Integer.parseInt(msgNr);
        // String iidQuery = "select iid from original where accid=1000 and msg_number=1669";
        Statement iidStmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet iidResult = iidStmt.executeQuery(iidQuery);
        while (iidResult.next())
            iid = iidResult.getString("iid");
        iidResult.close();
        iidStmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return iid;
}
```

The first query to get `accid` works. But the second query to get `iid` doesn't work, the result is always 0 row. As displayed in my code, I have already tried to convert `accid` to Integer, even I tried a hard value, but this query doesn't return a result. And it doesn't go inside the catch, because the query executed successfully. So I don't know what is wrong.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You shouls be using prepared statements here, but that being said, if the two columns in your where clause are integers, then I think your query should be working.

Comment: Are you sure accid gets value 1000 in that block and msgNumber is 1669? Your query looks like a nice candidate for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement`, never a regular `Statement`. Use `try-with-resources` for optimal resource closing, and don't use `getString()` when your columns are `int`s.

Comment: Maybe I don't know much about the sql api, but doesn't the fact that you immediately call `next()` skip the first line, so the `while`s never get executed?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no it doesn't. Time to read up on the JDBC API?

Comment: where do you set the `clientname` value?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca No, a call to `next()` is required before accessing a `RowSet`'s data.

Comment: @daniu Nope.  Not if that column is a number.  But prepared statements would fix this problem.

Comment: @Kayaman yep, I should, that's why I said "maybe I don't know much". Because I actually don't :)

Comment: does the second query (hard coded to your values) run when the first query is all commented out?

Comment: Hi, Thanks all for your answers and your hints. PreparedStatement fixed my issue. :)

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for your hint about `getInt()`, I always used `getString()` because I thought it will be converted to String automatically, but I will pay more attention from now on

Comment: @Ragnarsson it **will** be converted automatically. It's just not a good idea to convert them to Strings in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var "accid" is String Object

```
accid = accidResult.getString("accid");
```

You should probably always use prepared statements. Please see the updated function below:

```
public int getIID(String msgNr) {
    int accid=0;
    try {
        Statement accidStmt = conn.createStatement();
        String accidQuery = "select accid from accounts where name='" + clientname + "'";
        ResultSet accidResult = accidStmt.executeQuery(accidQuery);
        while (accidResult.next())
            accid = accidResult.getInt("accid");
        accidResult.close();
        accidStmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    int iid = 0;
    try {
        String iidQuery = "select iid from original where accid=? and msg_number=?";
        PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(iidQuery);  
        pst.setInt(1,accid);
        pst.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(msgNr));

        ResultSet iidResult=pst.executeQuery();  
        while (iidResult.next())
            iid = iidResult.getInt("iid");
        iidResult.close();
        iidStmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return iid;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter that it's a String though, since he was concatenating it to the query.

Comment: Hi, but "String accid = accidResult.getString("accid");" the accid type integer but he getString, accid  => null

Comment: That's not how it works. It converts the number to a String.

Comment: No problem, you should always use prepared statements. Prepared statements ensure that an attacker is not able to change the intent of a query